# pass data as variable from one componenent to other component using livewire 3 in laravel 10

Tags: laravel-blade, web-component, laravel-livewire

I have created my website layout using Blade and I've made each separate component with Livewire. Now I want to pass category id variable to my Livewire component.

Note: it works fine when I try with a simple value as a string.

My blade layout:

```php
@if (isset($pageHeader))   
    @livewire('blog.page-header', ['pageHeader' => $pageHeader]) 
@endif
```

Passing a variable from categories pages

```php
<x-slot name="pageHeader">
   {{ ($categories[0]->id ) }}
</x-slot>
```

I have tried searching in the official Livewire website documentation, version 2 and 3 both.
If we try with a simple value as string than its works fine.

This will cause error:

```php
@livewire('blog.page-header', ['pageHeader' => $pageHeader])
```

and simple string works fine:

```php
@livewire('blog.page-header', ['pageHeader' => 'pageHeader'])
```

Comment: The request is not clear. You should edit it and add the complete *page-header* component (class and view).  You should also post the complete error message.

Comment: Using a slot like that is not how you declare a variable, seems like that's what you're trying to?

Comment: @Qirel I tried to pass the value from my one page to my basic layout page and then tried to pass that value to the livewire component.